# Groupby Mutate Performance in Pandas

Tags: pandas, performance, numpy, vectorization, pandas-groupby

I often find myself trying to do the R equivalent of `groupby` then `mutate`, but as many people have pointed out simply using a `groupby` and `apply` suffers from major performance issues. So my question, what is the best (highest-performance) way to group a dataframe in pandas then based on some condition in that group, add a new column based on some calculations?

(I have searched and searched and I have not found any guides / steps on how to vectorize custom functions in pandas using numpy. All the answers to similar questions are always case-specific and don't generalize well.)

Example data:

```
df
Out[17]: 
             ID   ID2        col1        col2       col3    value
0             1     J       333.5       333.3      333.4      cat    
1             1     S       333.5       333.3      333.8      
2             2     J       333.7       333.3      333.8      cat
3             2     S       333.7       333.3      333.4      dog
4             3     L       333.7       333.8      333.9      
5             3     D       333.8       333.8      333.9      
6             4     S       333.8       333.6      333.7      cat
7             4     J       333.8       333.2      333.8      
8             4     J       333.8       333.7      333.9      
9             4     L       333.8       333.3      333.4      cat
```

Here are some examples, I run into constantly:

## 1) `apply` function to groups based on condition, return those results together with the original dataframe.

## `df.groupby(by=['ID']).apply(myfunc)`

```
def myfunc(group):
    group['new_col'] = len(group.query('''ID2=='T' & (col1>=col3 | px<=col2)''').unique())
    return group
```

## 2) Similar to 1), but only update one existing column based on some condition, then return that result together with the original dataframe.

## `df.groupby(by=['ID']).apply(update_func)`

```
def update_func(group):
     if 'S' in group['ID2'].values:
          group.loc[(group['value']=='cat'), 'other_column'] = False
     return group
```

Comment: Do you have any specific examples? This is kind of a open-ended question that make be considered to broad for this forum.

Comment: @ScottBoston I posted a couple examples, are they too broad in the current form?

Comment: Yes, it would help if you had inputs and expected outputs.  This is in my opinion.

Comment: @ScottBoston Added specific functions and data. I guess i struggle with apply functions on groups then getting back the original dataframe with the applied changes fast enough.

Comment: In Example 1, your function return should only be `len(group... .unique())`  then in your function call you `df['new_col'] = df.groupby(by='ID').apply(myfunc)`.  Return the values not the entire dataframe then set those values to a new column in the call.

Comment: In Example 2, I think you are trying to filter your dataframe.  Use `groupby` with `filter`.... Try something like this:  `df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: x.ID2.isin(['S']).any()).query('value == "cat"')`

Comment: For the first example, your recommendation outputs the correct results but with a single value per group. I can't simply assign this to a new column because the shapes are mismatched. I think I need to do some kind of broadcasting....

Comment: You need to add reset_index(level=0, drop=true) at the end to get indexes to match. I think.

Comment: @ScottBoston I added an answer for the first one that is an improvement but still slowish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a need for you to do your masking in the groupby, let see if this works faster for you.

```
d1 = df.assign(mask=np.logical_and(df.ID2 == 'J', (np.logical_or((df.col1 >= df.col3), (df.col1 <= df.col2)))))

dict = d1.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['mask'],'col1'].size).to_dict()
```

Comment: Seems faster but running %timeit gave this message: 
`The slowest run took 26.13 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.`
`1 loop, best of 3: 4.02 s per loop`

Comment: Never mind, it didn't give any weird messages when I reran it. If you have any similar strategies for the second example, please let me know! Thanks :)

Comment: The seoncd strategy was listed in the comments under the question above.  Try that statement.

Comment: Once I have grouped and applied a custom function that updates several cell values within that group, what is the best way to update or recombine this subset df back with the original?

Comment: I'd have to look at your original data and your results to let you know for sure.  Can you create a new question with that information?

Comment: I am testing this solution on ~5million rows and it doesn't seem to be scaling well :/ any advice?

Answer (score 0):

For the first example, I improved the function by using `numpy` operators and as @ScottBoston recommended, I changed the function to return just the values and then map them back to my original dataframe:

```
def my_func(group):
    mask = np.logical_and(group.ID2 == 'J', (np.logical_or((group.col1 >= group.col3), (group.col1 <= group.col2))))
    return len(group[mask].col1.unique())

dict = df.groupby(by=['ID'], sort=False).apply(my_func).to_dict() #This is a bit slow

df['new_col'] = df['ID'].map(dict) #This is fast
```

The slowest part is still the apply of the `numpy` conditions that has to operate on each group. If there was a way to operate on each one in parallel then that would be ideal as there is no need to do it sequentially like it is now.